# Events Deactivated and Activated only work once

Tags: events, windows-phone-7

When I am running the application and press the start button, the program runs the deactivated event, and If I back to the game, it runs the activated. But if then I press the start button, It doesn't runs the deactivated again. What's up?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it myself but it sounds like your event handler for "Deactivated" only gets hooked once (on application startup) and not when the application is (re)activated.

Where do you register your event handlers for activated/deactivated?

I guess you've already seen it but here is a good tutorial by Shawn Wildermuth:
[Tombstoning](http://wildermuth.com/2010/10/17/Architecting_WP7_-_Part_5_of_10_Tombstoning)

If it doesn't work with above guidelines, could you perhaps try to hook the Deactivated event yourself from the Activated event in code behind?

```
void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Deactivated += Application_Deactivated;
}
```

I don't think that above "hook" should be necessary though. Please post some code of how you register the events and the event handlers if you're still unsure.

HTH

Comment: these events are already at App.xaml.cs
I just added breakpoints to check, and followed the steps I wrote.